# Unable to reset the state of redux while refreshing the listing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Please see the attachment. same record gets append int he listing while switching between pages on website. Below is the code.

I have created a reducer to get the data from node and rendered the list. As you can see in the function render() where this.props.categoryListing renders the data on UI.

But when I return to my this listing page from any other page then the same record appears twice, thrice and more.
[image]

```
    renderCategory(category){
            const id = '/image_listing/' + category.id;
            return(
                <tr>
                    <td><a href={id}>{category.category}</a></td>
                    <td>{category.count}</td>
                    <td>
                        <span><img onClick={() => this.updateCategory(category.id)} className="edit" src="../../img/edit.png" /></span>
                        <span><img onClick={() => this.deleteCategory(category.id, category.category)} className="delete" src="../../img/delete.png" /></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        }


      render() {
         return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr className="tableHeader">
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Total Images</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                        {this.props.categoryListing.map(this.renderCategory.bind(this))}
                </table>
            </div>

        );
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        //debugger;
      return { 
            categoryListing: state.categoryListing,
            postRequestReducer: state.postRequestReducer
        };
    };
```

Please suggest the solution.

```
Action file code:

export function fetchCategoryListing() {
    var response = axios.get('http://localhost/get_category');
        return { 
            type: CATEGORY_LISTING, 
            payload:  response
    }
};

Reducer file code:
unction categoryReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CATEGORY_LISTING:
        return [ ...state, ...action.payload.data.result ];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default categoryReducer;
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Posted with more details

Comment: Where do the updateCategory/deleteCategory methods come from? Could you post the entire class?

Comment: Also, could you provide your current redux state, more specifically the categoryListing

Comment: updated the description

Comment: You seem to be always mergin the current state with the newly fetched data: `return [ ...state, ...action.payload.data.result ];` You probably don't want do to that.

Comment: Yes... correct.. what is the solution of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your response object, and the structure is `{"result":[{"id":60,"category":"Test","count":3}]}`

Based on the above response structure, in action file you should have:-

```
export function fetchCategoryListing() {
    var response = axios.get('http://49.50.102.36:3090/get_category');
    return { 
        type: CATEGORY_LISTING, 
        payload: response.result
    }
 };
```

Then inside your reducer you should have something like this:-

```
const initialState = {
    categoryListing: []
};

export default categoryReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
       case CATEGORY_LISTING:
           return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
       default:
           return state;
    }
}
```

Then finally you can add a unique key to your table rows like following:-

```
return(
     <tr key={category.id}>
         <td><a href={id}>{category.category}</a></td>
         <td>{category.count}</td>
         <td>
             <span><img onClick={() => this.updateCategory(category.id)} className="edit" src="../../img/edit.png" /></span>
                    <span><img onClick={() => this.deleteCategory(category.id, category.category)} className="delete" src="../../img/delete.png" /></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
)
```

I hope you find it helpful.